# How do I work with large, >30 GiB datasets that are formatted as SAS7DBAT files?

Tags: sql, pandas, database, sas, dask

I have these 30 GiB SAS7BDAT files which correspond to a year's worth of data. When I try importing the file using pd.read_sas() I get a memory-related error. Upon research, I hear mentions of using Dask, segmenting the files into smaller chunks, or SQL. These answers sound pretty broad, and since I'm new, I don't really know where to begin. Would appreciate if someone could share some details with me. Thanks.

Comment: i would try converting it to a SQLite database

Comment: Also consider if much of the data can be filtered or streaming-aggregated into a “smaller, more manageable” dataset without needing to be used in the original entirety. If so, this could be done as one-time streaming preprocessing step.

Comment: Sometimes you have to buy hardware to match the data.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

I am not aware of a partitioned loader of this sort of data for dask. However, the pandas [API](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_sas.html) apparently allows you to stream the data by chunks, so you could write these chunks to other files in any convenient format, and then process those either serially or with dask. The best value of chunksize will depend on your data and available memory.

The following should work, but I don't have any of this sort of data to try it on.

```
with pd.read_sas(..., chunksize=100000) as file_reader:
    for i, df in enumerate(file_reader):
        df.to_parquet(f"{i}.parq")
```

then you can load the parts (in parallel) with

```
import dask.dataframe as dd
ddf = dd.read_parquet("*.parq")
```